# Changing from primary to a custom menu changes my CSS navigation layout

Tags: css, navigation

I am needing help figuring out my main navigation bar. I had created it with the default navigation hook but now want the ability to hide pages so they do not show up on the main navigation. However whenever I add a new page it automatically shows up in the navigation (but I do not want this, such as the case of 2009 Galley, 2010 Gallery & 2011 Gallery under the GALLERY tab.)

[This is my website](http://fhlsociety.ca/)

This is the code I had in the header.php file

```
<div id="access" role="navigation">
<?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff */ ?>
<div class="skip-link screen-reader-text"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?></a></div>
<?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu.  The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used.  If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used.  */ ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- #access -->
```

Which gives me this great looking navigation.

[image]

Now I have tried to replace that with this

```
<div id="access" role="navigation">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main')); ?>
</div><!-- #access -->
```

And all I get is this

[image]

This is the CSS for my #access menu

```
#access {
    background: url(http://www.fhlsociety.ca/img/FHL-extras.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -236px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#access .menu-header,
div.menu {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 60px;
}

#access a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 100px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#access a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#access ul ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
    color: #333;
    background: none;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/*#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
    background-color: #990000;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #C7BD89;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 8px 17px;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}*/


#access ul li.current_page_item > a, #access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a, #access ul li.current-menu-item > a, #access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
    color: red;
}
```

What else am I missing? Or why might my styling not be there anymore? 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing an element `container_class` Try this -

```
<div id="access" role="navigation">
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array ( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'menu' => 'Main' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- #access -->
```

Comment: Hmmm..I remember trying something like that out last night when I was diagnosing it however it didn't work, I must of done it wrong. Is this is new hook in wordpress? I haven't been doing wordpress too long now but I don't remember having to put this hook in before. I just want to understand what I should do for next time, you know? And thanks!!

Comment: List of [Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) you can use with `wp_nav_menu`.

Comment: It ads 'menu-header' class to ul element for styling.